# Error while trying to reduce Seq[column] in spark scala - Due to data type mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sequence

I am trying to reduce modify open source library Deequ. I am trying to modify below code `metrics.reduce(_ and _)` to `metrics.reduce(_ + _)`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val metrics: Seq[Column]
```

Getting below error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '((`id` IS NOT NULL) + (`first` IS NOT NULL))' due to data type mismatch: '((`id` IS NOT NULL) + (`first` IS NOT NULL))' requires (numeric or calendarinterval) type, not boolean;;

I also tried `metrics.reduce(_.asInstanceOf[String] + _.asInstanceOf[String])`. But did not work.

I want to concatenate the values in `metrics` instead of doing a Boolean `AND` operation. Please help!

Comment: Well, the `Column`s against which you are trying to use `+` do not support this operation as the error message says.

Comment: How is this `metrics` value defined? Can you modify it?

Comment: I am yet to full analyze the open source library Deequ.  The values in `Column` are defined as Boolean.